# Augmentation with tf.data with the cross product to two datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord, data-augmentation

I would like to write a data augmentation step to my input pipeline, conceptually I have two datasets which can be fed to a generator as a pair where they will yield a bunch of output examples.

I have managed to achieve such a thing by doing the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def gen(a, b):
    for i in range(2):
        yield str(a) + " " + str(b) + " " + str(i)

a = tf.data.Dataset.range(3)
b = tf.data.Dataset.range(3)
dataset = b.interleave(lambda x: a.interleave(lambda y: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, 
            output_types=(tf.string), 
            args=(x, y)),
            num_parallel_calls = None))

for d in dataset:
    print (d.numpy())
```

This produces:

```
b'0 0 0'
b'0 1 0'
b'0 2 0'
b'0 0 1'
b'0 1 1'
b'0 2 1'
b'1 0 0'
b'1 1 0'
b'1 2 0'
b'1 0 1'
b'1 1 1'
b'1 2 1'
b'2 0 0'
b'2 1 0'
b'2 2 0'
b'2 0 1'
b'2 1 1'
b'2 2 1'
```

as expected. My issue here is that `gen` is (in my real case) a computationally expensive operation so I would like to use parallel calls where possible. My attempts to add num_parallel_calls so far has failed to yield performance gains.

Also, if it's important, my input dataset is coming from a `TFRecordDataset` which gives even more opportunity to add `num_parallel_calls` options, i.e.

```
raw_a = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(a_tfrecord_list)
a = raw_dataset.map(some_parsing_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `gen` is the expensive part, you should try to avoid using `Dataset.from_generator`. `Dataset.from_generator` requires running your Python generator for each element, which cannot be parallelized due to the Python global interpreter lock.

You could rewrite your dataset using `range` + `map` instead of `from_generator`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.data.Dataset.range(3)
b = tf.data.Dataset.range(3)

def make_dataset(x, y):
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(2)
  ds = ds.map(lambda i: tf.strings.as_string(x) + " " + 
              tf.strings.as_string(y) + " " + tf.strings.as_string(i))
  return ds

dataset = b.interleave(lambda x: a.interleave(lambda y: make_dataset(x, y)))

for d in dataset:
    print (d.numpy())
```

To parallelize the expensive computation, pass `num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE` to the `map` and `interleave` methods.

Comment: I have a similar situation and I am having a hard time speeding up the pipeline. I have two stage processing in the pipeline and I am using from_generator for each step with interleave. But I don't see any speed up. Psuedo code below. Any thoughts? Appreciate any help.

Comment: dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list_of_files)

dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(simple_gen_step1, 
                                output_types=(tf.string, tf.float32), args=(x,))

dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x1,y1, z1: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(simple_gen_step2, 
                                output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int16), args=(args1, args2,))